# Doc2Vec infer_vector not working as expected

Tags: python, text-classification, doc2vec

The program should be returning the second text in the list for most similar, as it is same word to word. But its not the case here.

```
import gensim
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument


data = ["I love machine learning. Its awesome.",
        "I love coding in python",
        "I love building chatbots",
        "they chat amagingly well"]


tagged_data=[TaggedDocument(word_tokenize(_d.lower()),tags=[str(i)]) for i,_d in enumerate(data)]

max_epochs = 100
vec_size = 20
alpha = 0.025

model = Doc2Vec(size=vec_size,
                alpha=alpha, 
                min_alpha=0.00025,
                min_count=1,
                negative=0,
                dm =1)

model.build_vocab(tagged_data)

for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    #print('iteration {0}'.format(epoch))
    model.train(tagged_data,
                total_examples=model.corpus_count,
                epochs=model.iter)
    # decrease the learning rate
    model.alpha -= 0.0002
    # fix the learning rate, no decay
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha

model.save("d2v.model")


loaded_model=Doc2Vec.load("d2v.model")
test_data=["I love coding in python".lower()]

v1=loaded_model.infer_vector(test_data)

similar_doc=loaded_model.docvecs.most_similar([v1])
print similar_doc
```

Output:

```
[('0', 0.17585766315460205), ('2', 0.055697083473205566), ('3', -0.02361609786748886), ('1', -0.2507985532283783)]
```

Its showing the first text in the list as most similar instead of the second text. Can you please help with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you won't get good results from `Doc2Vec`-style models with toy-sized datasets. Just four documents, and a vocabulary of about 20 unique words, can't create a meaningfully-contrasting "dense embedding" vector model full of 20-dimensional vectors.

Second, if you set `negative=0` in your model initialization, you're disabling the default model-training-correction mode (`negative=5`) – and you're not enabling the non-default, less-recommended alternative (`hs=1`). No training at all will be occurring. There may also be an error shown in the code output – but also, if you're running with at least `INFO`-level logging, you might notice other issues in the output.

Third, `infer_vector()` requires a list-of-word-tokens as its argument. You're providing a plain string. That will look like a list of one-character words to the code, so it's like you're asking it to infer on the 23-word sentence:

```
['i', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'c', ...]
```

The argument to `infer_vector()` should be tokenized exactly the same as the training texts were tokenized. (If you used `word_tokenize()` during training, use it during inference, too.)

`infer_vector()` will also use a number of repeated inference-passes over the text that's equal to the 'epochs' value inside the `Doc2Vec` model, unless you specify another value. Since you didn't specify an `epochs`, the model will still have its default value (inherited from `Word2Vec`) of `epochs=5`. Most `Doc2Vec` work uses 10-20 epochs during training, and using at least as many during inference seems a good practice.

But also:

**Don't try to call `train()` more than once in a loop, or manage `alpha` in your own code, unless you are an expert.**

Whatever online example suggested a code block like your...

```py
for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    #print('iteration {0}'.format(epoch))
    model.train(tagged_data,
                total_examples=model.corpus_count,
                epochs=model.iter)
    # decrease the learning rate
    model.alpha -= 0.0002
    # fix the learning rate, no decay
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha
```

...is a **bad** example. It's sending the effective `alpha` rate down-and-up incorrectly, it's very fragile if you ever want to change the number of `epochs`, it actually winds up running 500 epochs (100 * model.iter), it's far more code than is necessary.

Instead, don't change default `alpha` options, and specify your desired number of epochs when the model is created. So, the model will have a meaningful `epochs` value cached to be used by a later `infer_vector()`.

Then, **only call train() once**. It will handle all epochs & alpha-management correctly. For example:

```py
model = Doc2Vec(size=vec_size,
                min_count=1,  # not good idea w/ real corpuses but OK
                dm=1,  # not necessary to specify since it's the default but OK  
                epochs=max_epochs)
model.build_vocab(tagged_data)
model.train(tagged_data, 
            total_examples=model.corpus_count, 
            epochs=model.epochs)
```

Comment: I trained the model without loop and in infer_vector passed the tokenized words instead of whole sentence
``` 
data_test="I love coding in python".lower()
test_data=word_tokenize(data_test)
v1=loaded_model.infer_vector(test_data)
```
The ouput still shows first text from list as most similar:
`
[('0', 0.39219772815704346), ('2', 0.29952746629714966), ('3', 0.21126431226730347), ('1', 0.04621686041355133)]
`

Comment: Yes, per the very first point above, "you won't get good results from Doc2Vec-style models with toy-sized datasets."  So in addition to fixing your code, you'll need more data before you'll see results that start to make any sense. To train-up 20-dimensional vectors, I'd recommend at least 400 texts and a unique vocabulary of several thousand words.

Comment: Thanks for your help, am trying to group sentences with similar context, what other method will you suggest for this?

Comment: If you're simply trying to learn `Doc2Vec`, the tutorials with gensim can help, such as the one at <https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html>. It uses a small corpus ("lee corpus") of news stories that's bundled with `gensim` for testing purposes. It's still smaller than is usual for real work – just a few hundred docs of a few hundred words each – but with the similarly scaled-down training parameters, is sufficient to show some of the desired text-similarity qualities.